# PosixPath strips double slash

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm trying to use the python `pathlib` library to handle URLs. But the different `Path` objects seem to strip the double slashes off the URL. I've tried

```
import pathlib
print(pathlib.Path("foo//bar"))
>>> PosixPath("foo/bar")
print(pathlib.PurePath("foo//bar"))
>>> PurePosixPath("foo/bar")
```

I understand that I can solve this by working with the `os` library or simply operating with strings, but would rather prefer working with the `pathlib` library. How would I solve this while still working with the functionalities `pathlib` provides?

Comment: pathlib wasn't made for urls. have you considered using `urllib`?

Comment: I see - no I haven't. Will give it a shot, thanks :)